# CSS micro-optimization

Tags: css, micro-optimization

I'm considering micro-optimization of a huge CSS stylesheet and have a couple questions related to that:

1. Is lowercase better than uppercase for reducing file size?
2. Is background-position:right (5 chars); smaller than background-position:0 100%; (6 chars incl whitespace)?

Is there anything else that might help reduce file size? (Besides merging CSS selectors, properties etc ofcourse, that I'll have to do manually)

Thanks

Comment: I am quite curious : if you need nanoseconds speed improvement, what kind of project do you work on? It must not be a standard corporate website with a CMS behind, that's for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The character case doesn't matter, there's no difference in the number of bytes.
2. It depends on the browser:

The first statement is one byte shorter, but it also has a different meaning.

In general file size is not the only factor in the speed calculation. It also depends on how difficult it is for the browser to interpret it. So any overly clever CSS construct might squeeze some bytes out of the total size, but it's possible that the parsing process itself takes longer.

Back to your example: It is possible that second statement is a little bit slower, not just because of the extra space, but also the value consists of two tokens and depending on the internal representation of the background, the browser might have to do some unit conversions. On the other hand that keyword lookup can take a little more time, too, so it is really specific to a certain browser implementation. Most likely any gain would be in the range of nano-seconds and you shouldn't bother with this kind of optimization, as it **most likely will not pay off**. But if you really want to do this, you have to profile, i.e. measure the loading time.

**In general it's enough to remove all comments and all unnecessary whitespace**, but never do any development work on that "minified" source. Keep the original and recreate the compressed version when needed.

More information about this topic: [www.minifycss.com](http://www.minifycss.com/) and [this](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html).

Comment: 1) So its x bytes eitherway? 2) Care to elaborate? Thanks

Comment: Removing whitespace won't save anything if you're going to gzip the css - in fact, it could increase the size of the gzipped output.

Comment: Since I'm doing micro-optimization, Im dealing in nano-seconds. Anyway, if you were to choose for 'right' or '0 100%' what would you go with? :)

Comment: @Alexander: The *relative* compression might be better, but how can adding whitespace to a data stream decrease the *absolute* size of the compressed output? (Serious question!)

Comment: @Nimbuz: I don't have enough facts to choose one, it would be pure guessing :) The best thing would be to measure the loading time difference.

Comment: Is there any benchmarking tool for CSS? Sure, let me know your guess. :)

Comment: @DR: It's kind of difficult to explain without going into compression theory, but if you have say 5 spaces in a row in one place, and 4 spaces in a row in another place, gzip might create two separate "tokens" for them. But if you added spaces so they were all 6 spaces in a row, there would only be one token so better compression.

Comment: On second though, that is probably a bad example since minifying would replace all whitespace with a single whitespace character anyway. A better example would be `#fff` vs `#ffffff`. If you have another colour `0ffff0` then it could use `ffff` as a token in the latter case, but not the former. In general, all these differences are miniscule, so IMO it's not worth sacrificing readability.

Comment: You can go into compression theory, if you like :) But if I understand you correctly, better compression in such a way would only occur by chance, not in a general case, i.e. you cannot decrease the size of *every* zipped text file by randomly adding whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

You'd be much better serving the css gzipped, rather than worrying about things like that.

Comment: Yeah, but whitespace hardly makes a difference when gzipped, so it's a good way to get a lot of result.

Comment: @Nimbuz: actually, it's the first step. Gzip will make the biggest difference out of anything. The difference between gzip and minify+gzip is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this is a lot of trouble, you're time might be best spent elsewhere if you're trying to get better performance. Are you aware of Steve Souders work on High Performance Websites? http://stevesouders.com/hpws/